# How to call javascript function from .js file in swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

I tried to call a Javascript function from swift using below code but can't access the Javascript function

This is how I create the Javascript context object:

```
lazy var context: JSContext? = {
        let context = JSContext()

        guard let
            JSPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "IAV", ofType: "html")
            else {
                print("Unable to read resource files.")
                return nil
        }


        do {
            let iav = try String(contentsOfFile: JSPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            _ = context?.evaluateScript(iav)
        } catch (let error) {
            print("Error while processing script file: \(error)")
        }

        return context
    }()
```

//Set value to js

```
func setToken(Token:String)
    {
        let jsmethod = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("setIAVToken")
        let passParameter = jsmethod?.call(withArguments: [Token])
    }
```

The content of html file is

> sample IAV form
>
> ```
> </head>  
>
>
> <body > <header> </header> <main>
> <h1>Registration Form</h1>  
> <form id="myform" method="post">  
>  <div id="mainContainer">   <input type="button" id="start" value="Add Bank"> </div>
> ```
>
> var value="dhjhsd";
>
> ```
> var setIAVToken = function(token) {
> value= token;
> }
>
>
> $('#start').click(function() {
> var iavToken = value;
> alert(iavToken)
> dwolla.configure('uat');
> dwolla.iav.start('iavContainer', iavToken, function(err, res) {
> console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err) + ' -- Response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
> });
> }); </script> </html>
> ```

Comment: You can also check for https://www.raywenderlich.com/124075/javascriptcore-tutorial

Comment: already checked,there getting error in method let parseFunction = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("parseJson")
    guard let parsed = parseFunction?.call(withArguments: [response]).toArray() else {
      print("Unable to parse JSON")
      return []
    }
getting print("Unable to parse JSON") message

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use `WKWebView` (which is the new way to load web content in a webview in `iOS` since it uses WebKit and has lots of improvements like better memory allocation than it does WebView).

In a swift file `WebviewBridging.swift` in iOS you could have something like

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebviewBridging: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a WKWebView instance
        webView = WKWebView (frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webConfig)
        view.addSubview(webView!)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
        webView!.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
    }

    func callJSFunctionFromSwift(){
        webView!.evaluateJavaScript("changeBackgroundColor('red')", completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

In an `index.html` file on your iOS project folder you could have something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    function changeBackgroundColor(colorText) {
        document.body.style.background = colorText;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whenever you will call callJSFunctionFromSwift() in swift it will communicate with the WKWebView through XPC communication and evaluate your javascript code that will trigger the javascript function in index.html.

Answer (score 3):

In case of objective c do the following:

- `#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>` in header file.
- Next use this code inside viewcontroller.

`NSString *jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]` `pathForResource:@"JSFileName" ofType:@"js"];`

```
NSString *scriptString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
    context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
    [context evaluateScript:scriptString];
    JSValue *function = context[@"setMessage"];
    JSValue* result = [function callWithArguments:@[@"your custom string"]]; //pass the string whatever you want.
    [result toString]; // This will give the value in string format.
```

Comment: me also do same thing swift  :let JSPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jsfile", ofType: "js")
let alert = try String(contentsOfFile: JSPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
_ = context?.evaluateScript(alert)
let jsmethod = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("jsfunctionName") let passParameter = jsmethod?.call(withArguments: [message])

Comment: @rajes : Then what's the problem? It is the correct way to call a js function from ios.

Comment: me show alert(message) inside the setmessage function in js file, but can't show alert while executing

Comment: js for UIWebView,executing inside webViewDidStartLoad

Comment: load js on web view with dynamic value is my goal its possible?

Comment: You should not execute it `webViewDidStartLoad` it should be in `webViewDidFinishLoading`.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me the html file you are loading, is it from bundle or you are using a html string?

Comment: let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "alertfile", withExtension: "html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL);
        webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest);                                      in viewdidload

Comment: inside the html file added <script src= "alertfile.js"></script>

Comment: Are .js file and html file in the same folder?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the html file in normal browser and check `jsfunctionName` method return or log a value or not?  If your .js file have some syntax error then you will not get nothing.

Comment: both are same folder .   js filename is alertfile.js and html file name is alertfile.html

Comment: Ok. try once in browser.

Comment: @rajes : Do one thing. Copy whole js code including `<script></script>` tag and paste it inside the `<head></head>`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the html, use 
`<input type="button" id="start" value="Add Bank" onClick="setMessage()">` instead of `<input type="button" id="start" value="Add Bank">`

Also add `<input type="hidden" id="token" value="Token value">` inside the form to pass the token value.

In the javascript method:

```
<script>
  function setMessage() {
  var iavToken = document.getElementById("token").value;
  alert(iavToken)
  dwolla.configure('uat');
  dwolla.iav.start('iavContainer', iavToken, function(err, res) {
  console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err) + ' -- Response: ' +  JSON.stringify(res));
  });
  } 
</script>
```

Next invoke the javascript function using the following objective c.

```
NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setMessage()"]; 
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

P.S: You need to add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (or if you have the js file locally add it.) in the html to work with the js.